# How to apply datepicker to a textbox in mvc 5 without binding to a model date field

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Please how can we apply a date-picker to a text-box that is not bound to any model field?

For example, I have a 2 text boxes, dt1 & dt2 used to pass a date range to a controller, but the model for the this controller has as no date fields.

My view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    })
</script>

<div>
    <h2>Settled Report</h2><br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SettledReports", "POSReportController", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Accounts: @Html.DropDownList("accountNumber")
            Start Date: @Html.TextBox("dt1")
            End Date: @Html.TextBox("dt2")

            <input type="submit" value="View Report" />
        </p>
    }
    <h3>Transaction Breakdown</h3><br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr><th>SN</th><th>Card Type</th><th>Trans Count</th><th>Total Gross</th><th>Total Surcharge</th><th>Total Net</th></tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.summary)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sn)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cardType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.transCount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gross)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.surcharge)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.net)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr><td>SN</td><td>Merchant</td><td>Trans Date</td><td>Merchant ID</td><td>Terminal ID</td><td>STAN</td><td>Card No.</td><td>Trans Type</td><td>Approval Code</td><td>Gross Amount</td><td>POS Charge</td><td>Net Amount</td><td>Settlement Date</td></tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.detail)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sn)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.merchant)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.transDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.merchantID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.terminalID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stan)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cardNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.transType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.approvalCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gross)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.posCharge)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.net)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.settlementDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be using a view model, but what datepicker - a jquey plugin of the HTML5 datepicker?

Comment: Please either would do. thanks!

Comment: Show your view. If you want the HTML5 datepicker, then the input needs `type="date"`, other wise you need to attach a jquery plugin to the element (using an `id` or class name)

Comment: I have attached the view in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.TextBox("dt1", null, new {@class="date-picker"})
```

and move

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    })
 </script>
```

after the `</div>`

If you're using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) (you can install it with this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.Datepicker/)), you can create a daterange with

```
<div class="input-daterange">
    @Html.TextBox("dt1", null, new {@class="input-small"})
    <span class="add-on">to</span>
    @Html.TextBox("dt2", null, new {@class="input-small"})
</div>
```

and the javascript code,

```
$(".input-daterange input").each(function (){
    $(this).datepicker(“clearDates”);
});
```

Comment: $('.date-picker').datepicker() need to have bootstrap-datepicker plugin, do you have the reference in the <head> section?

Comment: i guess bootstrap-datepicker plugin does not come with MVC5?

Comment: no, but you can install it with Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.Datepicker/

Comment: @CharlesO, You can also use the jquery-ui datepicker which will already be included in your app by default.

Comment: @CharlesO is right, just include it in your layout.

Answer (score -1):

I face the same problem and that is my steps to solve it:
1. install bootstrap datepicker:
right click on solution --> manage nuget packages for solution --> search for bootstrap datepicker and install it
2. in file _Layout.cshtml add those files "bootstrap-datepicker.css & bootstrap-datepicker.js" :
Note: add the files after bootstrap and jquery script files to be like that :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

@*Define Bootstrap DatePicker to use in index page*@
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

3. in your view page add the html element for the datepicker:

   @Html.TextBox("datepicker1", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
4. use this script:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {  
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element  
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();  
    })  
</script>
```